# Receiving files from Java server to Android. accept() not working

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, connection

Hi guys I'm creating simple interactive android application. Server runs Java. 
It turns out, that I can not receive files from server.

Android code is following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public DataReceiving dataReceiving;
public DataTransfer dataTransfer;
private EditText inputData;
private Button sendParameters;
private Button startComputation;
public TextView displayText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputData= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    sendParameters=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    startComputation=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    displayText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);




    startComputation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String numberOfGates=inputData.getText().toString();
            ArrayList send=new ArrayList();
            send.add(numberOfGates);                
            dataTransfer=new DataTransfer();
            dataTransfer.execute(send);

        }
    });

    sendParameters.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataReceiving=new DataReceiving();
            dataReceiving.execute();
        }
    });

}
public  class DataReceiving extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList>
{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList receivedData=new ArrayList();
        Log.i("DataReceiving", "doInbackgroung works");
        try {
            receivedData=receive();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DataReceiving", "Problems with receive method. Issue with class");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DataReceiving", "Problems with receive method. Issue with IO");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return receivedData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          displayText.setText(result.toString());

        }


}


public ArrayList receive () throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Log.i("receive method", "works");
        ServerSocket s= new ServerSocket(8888);
        Log.i("receive method", "ServerSocket(8888)");
        Socket incoming =s.accept();
        Log.i("receive method", "accept()");
        ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
        Log.i("receive method", "ios");
        ArrayList b=new ArrayList();
        b = (ArrayList) ios.readObject();               
        Log.i("receive method", "data were received");
        ios.close();
        incoming.close();
        s.close();
        return b;
    }





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the Log

```
06-18 18:08:51.709: D/dalvikvm(2160): GC_CONCURRENT freed 69K, 7% free 2760K/2952K, paused 78ms+85ms, total 261ms
06-18 18:08:52.079: D/gralloc_goldfish(2160): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 18:09:05.090: I/DataReceiving(2160): doInbackgroung works
06-18 18:09:05.099: I/receive method(2160): works
06-18 18:09:05.099: I/receive method(2160): ServerSocket(8888)
```

It seems like Socket incoming =s.accept(); doesn't work and I have no idea why

Here is Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Server side is very simple

```
Socket s=new Socket("192.168.1.110", 8888);
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
ArrayLIst b = new ArrayList();
b.add("It Works");
oos.writeObject(b);
oos.close();
s.close();
```

I will be very appreciated for any Ideas, how to fix this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the client part is working right, it stops at the accept method. So the problem is in the server which never gets to connect. 
The server part should be like this:

```
try {
   Socket s = new Socket();
   InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.110");
   SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, 8888);
   s.connect(sockaddr, 20000); // 20 seconds time out
   ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
   ArrayLIst b = new ArrayList();
   b.add("It Works");
   oos.writeObject(b);
   oos.close();
   s.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 .....
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, can you from the server use a telnet 192.168.1.110 8888? can you connect? if you cannot make the connection, plese check your firewall, disable your a while and try again the telnet.